# Get QStandardItem for the custom context menu of a QTreeView

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qt5.3

I have a subclass of QTreeView. I need a custom context menu for specific items in it. To get this I set the context menu policy and connect the signal "customContextMenuRequested" in the constructor of the subclass of QTreeView:

```
setContextMenuPolicy( Qt::CustomContextMenu );

QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested( const QPoint & ) ), this, SLOT( onCustomContextMenu( const QPoint & ) ) );
```

Now, in the slot function "onCustomContextMenu" I get the position for the context menu creation as a QPoint. I would like to get the QStandardItem that is shown on this position. I tried this:

```
void t_my_tree_view::onCustomContextMenu( const QPoint &point )
{
  QModelIndex index = this->indexAt( point );
  QStandardItem* item_ptr = m_item_model->item( index.row, index.column() );
}
```

m_item_model is a pointer to the QStandardItemModel that is the model in this subclass of the QTreeview.

The problem is, that the "item_ptr" that I get is wrong sometimes, or it is NULL. It will be NULL if my model looks like this:

invisibleRootItem
|-item_on_level_1
  |-item_on_level_2
  |-item_on_level_2
  |-item_on_level_2  <-- this is the item where the right click was
  |-item_on_level_2

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the item that i rightclick?

Answer (score 2):

if your `contextMenuRequest` selects the `TreeItem` then you could use `QTreeView::currentIndex()` to get the actual selected `QModelIndex`.

Use `QStandardItemModel::itemFromIndex(const QModelIndex&)` to get the pointer to the `QStandardItem`.

Just in case, check if the ptr is null and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

You should map `QPoint` coordinates to `view->viewport()` coordinates.

Prefferable way is to implement custom `QStyledItemDelegate` with overriding `editorEvent`, like:

```
bool LogDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent* event, QAbstractItemModel* model, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {
            QMouseEvent* me = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
            if (me->button() == Qt::RightButton)
            {
                QMenu menu;
                QAction* copy = new QAction("Copy", this);
                connect(copy, SIGNAL( triggered() ), SIGNAL(copyRequest()));
                menu.addAction(copy);
                menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
                copy->deleteLater();
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
}
```